# How to make a non-blocking recv from perl socket

Tags: perl, sockets

When making a recv call on a TCP socket and when it turns out that the recv call is blocking even though the socket itself was set up in non-blocking mode, how does one implement a non-blocking recv on the perl socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [4 argument version of `select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#select) to check whether there is input on the socket before you try to `recv` from it.

Answer (score 3):

If your looking for a simpler interface to `select` mentioned by mobrule [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Select) provides an OO interface to it.

Comment: IO::Socket provides some nice API cleanup as well.  I always use IO::Select and IO::Socket instead of the built-in functions.  The API is a million times easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag to your `recv` call.